# Problems with Punctuation in Title using ElementCriteriaModel

Tags: elementcriteriamodel

I've noticed something odd and I can't find anything in the documentation.

I'm writing a plugin and when I use `ElementCriteriaModel` to find an existing entry like so:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'entryHandle';
$criteria->title = 'The Title & Stuff';
$existingEntry = $criteria->first();
```

The entry is not found, and I believe it's because of the punctuation. The entry is clearly in the `craft_content` table (with the exact title including punctuation). Is there some sort of processing I need to do before setting the title criterion?

Thanks!

Comment: Which character set and collation is your database using?

Comment: character set: UTF 8, collation: utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: You might need to treat the ampersand as a special character. Try this and see what happens: $criteria->title =escapeParam("The Title & Stuff");  Just an untested guess.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code with a similar query in a local database and am getting the results you'd expect. So the code seems accurate. Aside from environmental variables that may be at play, the only part of the example code above that I see a potential issue with the line:

```
$criteria->section = 'entryHandle';
```

It's unclear what you may mean by `entryHandle`.  This value should be the `sectionHandle`. If `entryHandle` means `slug`, then the `$criteria->section` may need to get updated to be `$criteria->slug = 'entryHandle';`